# optional parameter based off boolean template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm trying to declare a template function that...

- has *3 parameters* if template boolean is *true*
- has only *2 parameters* if template boolean is *false*

Is this possible?

The code below compiles, however both versions require 3 parameters. I need it to only need 2 parameters when the template *boolean is false* and the resulting usage of the function - the user only needs to supply *2 parameters*.

Ideally this is a single function, so code duplication can be avoided as the function definition is very simple.

*Static:
Iterate thru area, apply hash to nodes.*

*Dynamic:
Iterate thru area, transform node by 2D rotation, apply hash to node.*

Ideally the selection of the logic to use can be evaluated at compile time aswell

*if constexpr(Dynamic) ...*

```
template<bool const Dynamic>
void setHashAt(rect2D_t area, uint32_t const hash, std::conditional_t<Dynamic, v2_rotation_t const&, void> vR)
```

Thanks!

Comment: is the template parameter only to select number of parameters? Asking because for different number of parameters you just need two overloads, no template required

Comment: yes in this case I want to define a single function, rather than two. It would be a copy and paste job for the meat of the function If I overloaded it. Would be nice to have it all in one, cause they are very similar.

Comment: no, no copy pasta needed. The one with less params is `void foo(first,second) { the_actual_func_with_all_params(first,second); }`. Where the actual function can have a default for the missing one

Comment: no matter what you do, a function with 3 params is a different function than a function with 2 params. On the other hand to avoid code duplication it isnt necessary to make it a template

Comment: Can't you use default assignment to prevent all of this and KISS (Keep it simple s... ;-) )

Comment: lol. Yeah then the "static" (Dynamic = false) would iterate through the area, applying the hash to all the nodes with a transform by a 2D rotation. Ideally, only the "dynamic" version would do this. the static version would do exactly the same, without the extra transform. That's basically the meat of the function.

Comment: Without some body of this function it is hard to tell why you think simple overload is a bad solution.

Comment: overloading is a solution, it's just a little bit messy. Having to write 2 functions that differ by a very small change. I would also like to throw in some debugging helpers that will further complicate the code duplication.

Comment: sorry, but I think you didnt understand. The difference between the two overloads must not be more than minimal. You can write two overloads and the only code that is duplicated is what is different between the two, ie actually its no duplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can do that through SFINAE;

```
#include <type_traits>

template <const bool EnableThird, std::enable_if_t<EnableThird, int> = 0>
void dynamic_parameter_count(int one, int two, int three) {
    std::cout << "EnableThird was true\n";
}

template <const bool EnableThird, std::enable_if_t<!EnableThird, int> = 0>
void dynamic_parameter_count(int one, int two) {
    std::cout << "EnableThird was false\n";
}
```

And you can then simply invoke using;

```
dynamic_parameter_count<true>(1, 2, 3);
dynamic_parameter_count<false>(1, 2);
```

This works by enabling or disabling one of the template instantiations based on the template parameters. You do, in fact, need two templates for this as far as I know. I'm not sure if you can do this in one template.

You can also simply specify two versions for the same function, however;

```
void parameter_count(int one, int two, int three) {
    std::cout << "3 Parameters\n";
}

void parameter_count(int one, int two) {
    std::cout << "2 Parameters\n";
}
```

To me, without knowing the context you are working in, this seems more logical.

Or even:

```
#include <optional>

void parameter_count(int one, int two, std::optional<int> three = {}) {
    if (three.has_value()) {
        std::cout << "3 Parameters\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "2 Parameters\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: That is very simple. Unfortunately it still needs to separate into two functions.

Comment: @J.Tully see my edit, maybe the optional variant might work for you.

Comment: The "meat" of the function is very similar in both cases - the only difference being a transform of the current point being iterated by the optional parameter, which is a rotation.

Comment: Ah nice alternative! If it isn't possible to to do a compile time variant of this, that seems like the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simple overload seems simpler, but to directly answer your question, you might (ab)use of variadic template and SFINAE:

```
template<bool Dynamic,
         typename ... Ts,
         std::enable_if_t<(Dynamic == false && sizeof...(Ts) == 0)
                          || (Dynamic == true && sizeof...(Ts) == 1
                              && std::is_convertible_v<std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Ts...>>,
                                                      v2_rotation_t>)
                         , bool> = false>
void setHashAt(rect2D_t area, uint32_t const hash, const Ts&...   vR);
```

With the caveat that 3rd argument should be deducible (so no `{..}`).

Comment: Interesting approach!

Answer (score 1):

This is a small variation to your solution

```
#include <type_traits>

struct None{};

template<bool select>
void foo(int, std::conditional_t<select, int, None> = None{}) {
}

int main() {
    foo<false>(1);
    foo<true>(1,2);
    // foo<false>(1,2); // fails
    // foo<true>(1); // fails
}
```

I don't think this is a clean solution, but instead overloading and refactoring the code to avoid duplication should be the right approach (as suggested in comments).

Comment: interesting - yeah I was hoping to use void there where you have "None" and that the compiler was smart enough to drop it from the function arguments. Nope. This is an interesting alternative.

Comment: `foo<false>(1, {})` is possible though. (which might be problematic as `foo<true>(1, {})` is correct).

Comment: Agree. There can be a simple fix by disabling default/aggregate initialization, but in the end we all agree that the correct solution seems to be normal overloading...